# Significado de "dona" em português

Tags: português-brasileiro

Qual é a significado da palavra **dona** na lingua portuguesa? Ou seja, é equivalente a qual palavra em inglês?

Eu ouvi que as pessoas usam para respeitar pessoas idosas, e também a faxineira para chamar a pessoa para quem trabalha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN ENGLISH

**I gather you refer to "dona" as a form of address**.  Should that be the case,
**"dona"** can be described as the Portuguese counterpart of **"Miss"** or **"Mrs"**.  In English, however, such forms of address are usually followed by the woman's surname whereas in Portuguese one's given name follows "dona".

Suppose "Maria Vieira" is **a middle-aged married woman** who lives next door.

In Brazil, your neighbor will usually be addressed as  "Dona Maria" or simply "Maria" if you are close friends and there is some intimacy.  If she is an aged woman or if you're much younger than she is, you will certainly use "dona" for fear of being considered ill-mannered. The exception would be if she asks you to drop the "dona".

Likewise, in English your next door neighbor will be "Mrs. Vieira", or simply "Maria", if there's some degree of intimacy. Her daughter will be addressed to as "Miss Vieira"

**The only real difference is what follows the title: a given name after "dona" and a surname after "Miss" or "Mrs".**  Both titles express some formality and/or good manners.

IN PORTUGUESE:

Sua pergunta parece referir-se a "dona" como forma de dirigir-se a uma mulher. Sendo esse o caso, eu diria que "dona" é o equivalente de "Miss" ou "Mrs" na língua inglesa.  Enquanto que em inglês esses títulos são seguidos por um sobrenome, em português é o nome de batismo que segue "dona".

Suponha que "Maria Vieira" é sua vizinha. No Brasil, ela seria chamada "dona Maria".  Chamá-la de "Maria" simplesmente, indicaria um grau de intimidade e/ou amizade.  Se você é bem mais novo do que "Maria Vieira", chamá-la de "Maria" sem que ela assim o pedisse, seria considerado falta de educação, ou uma tentativa inadequada de parecer íntimo.

Na prática, a única diferença entre "dona" e Mrs/Miss, é o uso do primeiro nome após "dona" e o uso do sobrenome após Miss/Mrs.  O uso de ambos os títulos expressa. um certo grau de formalidade e boa educação.

Quanto a patroa dirigir-se a faxineira pelo seu nome e esta usar "dona" ao falar com a patroa, é o que ocorre habitualmente **embora tenha mais a ver com distinção de classes do que boa educação**. Uma assimetria que talvez devesse ser questionada.

Comment: perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

O Dicionário *Houaiss* tem uma definição completa que trata do caso da idosa, bem como a pessoa para quem a faxineira trabalha:

> substantivo feminino
> **1** *Rubrica: história.*
> título concedido às senhoras de famílias nobres (abrev.: d. ou D.) [Us. como tratamento honorífico, de que era precedido o nome próprio de mulheres pertencentes às famílias reais de Portugal e do Brasil, estendeu-se a todas as mulheres distinguidas por algum título de respeito, como as casadas, viúvas, religiosas.]
> **2** *Derivação: por extensão de sentido. Regionalismo: Brasil.*
> mulher casada; esposa
> **3** proprietária; senhora
> **4** *Regionalismo: Brasil. Uso: informal.*
> qualquer mulher

Não existe uma palavra equivalente em inglês, mas, em geral, a palavra *[lady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady#:%7E:text=%22Lady%22%20is%20used%20before%20the,duke%2C%20marquess%2C%20or%20earl.)* chega perto do significado.

**Observações:**

No Brasil, frequentemente se diz, por exemplo, "Dona Maria" como forma de respeito, mas não tem prática equivalente em inglês, porque, em inglês, se usa o sobrenome com Mrs. (se for casada), "Mrs. Smith", ou Ms. (se for não casada) "Ms. Smith". Outra alternativa comum em inglês é "Ma'am" sem dizer o nome.

A palavra *lady* pode significar *dona de casa* ou *senhora*. Ela também é usada como título de nobreza..

Comment: Oi Sid, você postou uma resposta à essa [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8255/2764) e depois a deletou. Você não quer reconsiderar? Ela me pareceu uma resposta válida.

Comment: @stafusa. Acho que usei terminologia errada. Sem estudar mais a gramática, não sou muito qualificado para.responder.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno imediato! Bem, a resposta é sua e acho você decide sobre ela - inclusive por isso te contactei aqui ao invés de simplesmente clicar no "undelete". Mas seria bom para esse site ter mais movimento e, em geral, se houver algo a ser corrigido na sua resposta, alguém colocaria num comentário. Também acho importante ser cuidadoso ao postar, mas se eu fosse responder só quando me considerasse qualificado, não teria quase postagem alguma, dado que sou mero usuário da língua. Mas, de novo, siga teu julgamento, claro, eu apenas quero dizer que não é preciso ter tanto receio assim.