# Como usar o pronome relativo “na/o qual”?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronomes

> Uma cena do filme O Homem Urso **na qual** o diretor está ouvindo as fitas
> do homem homônimo sendo destroçado por ursos selvagens.

O pronome está sendo usado corretamente?  A preposição “na” corresponde à regência do verbo “ouvir”? Mas “ouvir”, nesse caso, não seria um verbo transitivo direto?

Comment: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/onde-em-que-no-qual/34035

Comment: Por mais d'eu achar a frase esquisita, já que é equivalente a “numa cena do filme O Homem Urso, o diretor está ouvindo as fitas do homem homônimo sendo destroçado por ursos selvagens”, “na qual” me parece se referir a “uma cena do filme O Homem Urso”. “Em” refere-se a “a qual”, e “qual” é um pronome relativo (https://www.normaculta.com.br/pronomes-relativos/) que é sempre acompanhado de artigo, “a(s)” ou “o(s)”, e está se referindo a “uma cena do filme O Homem Urso” .

Answer (score 1):

"Na" corresponde a "uma cena" e está usado corretamente.